# I have a error concerning my emulator in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an error in android studio

init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!

I tried different options but could not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

if u have old sdk and android studio 
you can goto tools > android studio > Avd manager
 and edit the current AVD you have , in that change the option for faster performance to another option like (save screen shot for faster performance). could be helpful.

or its latest version, now a days it has option for emulated performace , in that you can try changing either or and try if problem solved..

its mainly because of ur graphics driver problems,i think

hope it helps,

thanks,